# Android - How to Check directions of a Object/Image?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, directions

I wanted to know how to determine which direction an image or generic object, is moving (right, left, up or down). And as "allow" drag and drop only in a certain direction, thanks ^^

Comment: apologizes you're right, the fact is that being Italian, and my English is not perfect, I have avoided giving too many explanations for not confusing ^^' . Anyway I'm working with the collision detect between two imageview, I can realize the collision, but can not prevent the two images overlap

Comment: It's ok, but you should try to elaborate on what you have tried and where you are confused.

Comment: the point is that after the collision do not know how to continue DX.

Answer (score 0):

Store your Object's location and compare it with the location when your Object has moved to see which direction the Object is moving.

Comment: thanks for the reply ^^, could you do me a small example?I don't know how do I save the location of the object,i just started with Android and some things, I still do not have clear ^^'